# Can´t drop table - no reaction

Tags: mysql

I try to `drop` a table from my schema in MYSQL workbench but it´s not working: I tried it a few times but stopped it after 30Minutes time, it seems like the workbench freezes...

I also tried to `truncate` the table, but this is also not working :( Normaly it takes less than a second to drop a table) - so what´s the problem and how can I solve it? (The table is about 200MB).

That´s what I tried:

```
TRUNCATE Table1;

DROP TABLE Table1;
```

Thanks for your support!

Comment: "Not working" , not working how? Does the table really called `1` ?

Comment: It´s working: but I cannot image how it should take so long: it´s still running (for over 30Minutes now) and it normally takes less than 5Seconds to drop a table with about 100MB. And no: The table is called TableY

Comment: Maybe there is an open transaction on this table ? Meaning someone forgot to commit ?

Comment: @sagi how can I see if there´s an open transaction on it?

Comment: Mmm, guess there is an easier way, but does a simple update on the table executes correctly ?

Comment: No-it´s not working

Comment: Then yes, some one forgot to commit :)

Comment: I´m not able to see who it is: how can I?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. Try googling -> `MySQL Who is locking the table`

Answer (score 0):

Open the **mysql command line client** and perform `drop table table1;`
 again.Hopefully it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason for table lock is `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT`.

Try the following:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
TRUNCATE `database_name`; 
###_or_ DROP `database_name`;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

You can run those from console or from Workbench. Note that whatever is locking it, is doing it for a reason. Make sure that you have a **valid backup** before `truncate` anything.

Hope this helps.